# Best Pagination plugin for an Angular Project

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

I am working on an Angular & Bootstrap application. Please suggest me best pagination plugin that i can use.

I have tried like this:
https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

but it uses own directive eg. **dir-paginate** instead of **ng-repeat**

E.g. `<li dir-paginate="item in list.collection | itemsPerPage: 3" pagination-id="list.id">ID: {{ list.id }}, item: {{ item }}</li>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with : [angular-ui Bootstrap Pagination](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

The Library is maintained by the core team and it is very stable. Also since you are already using bootstrap so, it will be ideal for you.

Comment: i have checked it, could you please suggest me any demo if available to use it. I didn't found it.